# What happens in Android with code that is not supported in old devices

Tags: android

For instance, I have a method in my Activity class that looks like this

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = buttonsContainer.getViewTreeObserver();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(mButtonsObserverListener);
                } else {
                    observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(mButtonsObserverListener);
                }
```

I can suppress lint warnings, but what happens on old Android 2.2 where this code will be executed? There is no 'removeOnGlobalLayoutListener' function in old SDK, how does this compile and run on that platform?

Answer (score 2):

It does compile since your `android:minSdkVersion` is high enough. It will also be installed on your device. You app will keep running till it has to execute that unknown code. Your app will simply crash now.

Why don't you try it yourself on an Emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will throw a `MethodNotFoundException` and your app will either crash or - if there is one - jump to a surrounding `try`/`catch` block.

(And on Android 1.6, a `ClassNotFoundException` will be thrown when the class containing the code is loaded rather than when the code inside it is executed)